# Backbone.js app - browser refresh on source save

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm developing a Backbone.js app, and running it locally with simple Node.js based http-server: https://npmjs.org/package/http-server

I'd like for the browser to refresh the page when any of the source files are changed. What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: I think livereload is something you are looking for

Comment: If you refer to the LiveReload app, then it's probably it, but it cost 10$. I'd leave it for the last option.

Comment: Ok I gave up after trying to figure out Grunt for some time and bought LiveReload. It works!

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do that using Grunt. There's a plugin for it at https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-watch that will run specified tasks when certain files are changed, and it includes live reload functionality.